# SSIS Package failing to access UNC path it has permissions to

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Trying to run an SSIS package that tries to access `\\fileserver\share\file.txt`, but the SSIS job returns:

> "File System Task:ERROR: File or directory "\\fileserver\share\file.txt" represented by connection "Flat File Connection Manager" does not exist.

Permissions on the share and the NTFS permissions allow both the service account running SSIS and the user running the package read/write access to file.txt

If the user RDP's into the SSIS server they can access the UNC path without issue.

Triple-verified permissions using 'effective access' directly on file.txt and permissions are set correctly.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491525/ssis-does-not-recognize-file-path